# Is it safe to modify an entity framework migration so that instead of dropping and recreating an index, it does it a different way?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations, clustered-index

Azure doesn't support "heap" tables, so I cannot "drop" the main index.

**EntityFramework** generates a migration that needs to drop and then recreate an index.  Is it safe, before running the migration, to modify it so that instead of dropping and recreating the index, it copies the data to a new table with the new index, deletes the old table, then renames the new table to the old table's name?

The final state of the database, in the end, would be the same, so I think it's a safe change to make.

The model snapshot, etc. should all be the same.

Comment: I think you are going to create your own implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`

Answer (score 0):

We modify migrations regularly to create an additional index or to create a view instead of a table.

```
public override void Up() {
    Sql(@"CREATE VIEW ... ");
}

public override void Down() {
    Sql(@"DROP VIEW ... ");
}
```

As long as the final state of the database is compatible with you model, it is safe. You should only be careful about the "Down" part of the migration. If there is any chance you will ever run it, you should modify not only the `Up` method but also the `Down` method in your migration.